# Array vs. pointer function parameter, interesting MSVC behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

I noticed an interesting behavior of MSVC: functions with an array parameter are mangled differently than functions with a pointer parameter.

```cpp
void foo(double a[3]);
```

is mangled as `?foo@@YAXQEAN@Z`. If I demangle the parameter type back, it is `double * const` (this is what the compiler complains about, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3jh6xdfax)). On the other hand,

```cpp
void foo(double *a);
```

is mangled as `?foo@@YAXPEAN@Z`, demangled parameter type is `double *`. Notice the `Q`/`P` difference in the mangled name. And this is not just a cosmetic difference, we get a linker error if the function definition and the declaration doesn't match in this regard.

Is this behavior standard compliant? Even, does a top-level `const` modifier make any sense for the linker? What does it mean?

Comment: They should. Fixed arrays aren't pointers and vice versa.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”" (https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) Also, the difference is still there if I remove the `3`.

Comment: These two function declarations mean the exact same thing: `void foo(int);` and `void bar(int const);`.  Likewise these two: `void baz(int*);` and `void quux(int* const);`.  The top-level `const` qualifier for the parameter doesn't mean anything.  The `const` is used in the definition and affects the parameter (disallowing the parameter value to be changed), but isn't part of the signature.

Comment: An array parameter is passed as a pointer to the 1st element, so `void foo(double a[3]);` is identical to `void foo(double *a);`. Why the compiler is adding `const` to the first one, I have no idea. Sounds like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment but I agree with @Remy (see his comment), I see no obvious reason for the "const" in the error message so suspect it's a bug, possibly (wild guess only) because it may initially be flagging "a" as "const" since arrays aren't assignable (even though it's not really an array in this context). It may be forgetting to remove the "const" even though it correctly treats it as a pointer type in the actual linker error.

Whether this is actually the case or just wild (far-fetched) speculation (probably/possibly), parameters in function prototypes shouldn't normally be declared "const" if they're value parameters (though I know it's not declared that way here but read on). It's confusing for readers since it makes no difference to the caller, and it makes no technical difference to the compiler itself (that I'm aware of). The function's signature remains unchanged whether it's "const" or not (again, applicable to value parameters only). Only in the function's definition would you want to make such values "const" if they're not modified inside the function, no different than any other "const" variable you would define locally in the function (just because they're parameters makes no difference in this regard). For further details see bullet 1 in the "Solution" section here: https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/28/gotw-6b-solution-const-correctness-part-2/.

The upshot is that "const" doesn't make any difference in the prototype itself as far as the compiler is concerned (for value parameters). It sees "double *" and "double * const" as being the same (in the prototype) so presumably it's free to display the error as you're seeing it if that's how it's dealing with it internally (for whatever reason). I'd still maintain it's a bug however (or very confusing anyway) to display it this way for end-users (given that "const" isn't present in their own code).

Note (FWIW) the "decltype" of "foo" still correctly shows the parameter as a "double *" (no "const" present)